# Python socket send data

Tags: python, sockets

I have started working on a chat. When a client writes something in the chat its sends everyone his message including himself. My question is how to prevent sending the message he wrote to him from the server?

This is my server code:

```
listening_socket = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
listening_socket.bind( ("", 1234) )
listening_socket.listen(5)
open_sockets = []

while True:
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([listening_socket] + open_sockets,
                                        [listening_socket] + open_sockets,
                                        [])
    for i in rlist:
        if i is listening_socket:
            new_socket, addr = listening_socket.accept()
            open_sockets.append(new_socket)
        else:
            data = i.recv(1024)
            if data == "":
                open_sockets.remove(i)
                print "Connection closed"
            else:
                print repr(data)
                for k in wlist:
                    k.send(data)  # <==== here it sends the message to every one
```

Comment: `i == listening_socket` is preferred to `i is listening_socket`, as the `is` compares reference not value, which can lead to unexpected results (`5 is 5` but not necessarily `123456 is 123456`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
for k in wlist:
    if k != i:
        k.send(data)
```

Comment: Thanks!!!
I have another question, If I want also to pass a name, so everyone in the chat would be able to see who wrote each message. How can I do it?

Comment: Why doesn't each client prepend his/her name to the messages it sends? The server doesn't need to know. If it **does** need to know, you have a slightly bigger problem, because your server keeps absolutely no data on its clients besides the socket handle